# Convert a unicode input to string for comparison

Tags: python

i am writing code which parses a word document table and compares to a keyword which is an ascii string

```
tyring = unicode((ListTables[0].Rows[x])).encode('utf-8')
tryingstring = tyring.encode('ascii')
print 'trying string' ,tryingstring
```

ERROR BELOW:

```
tyring = unicode((ListTables[0].Rows[x])).encode('utf-8','ignore')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 201, in __str__
    return str(self.__call__())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 201, in __str__
    return str(self.__call__())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uf07a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It does not print it should though since trying string is a ascii string now ?

Comment: Can create a small, complete example of the error?  What is the value of `ListTables[0].Rows[x]`?  Somehow the code is trying to convert a Unicode string with non-ASCII characters to ASCII, but the code you are showing does not show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to your original posting:

```
if tr1_find.search(str(ListTables[0].Cell(x,y))):
    print 'Found'
    value  = ListTables[0].Cell(x,y+1)
```

`ListTables[0].Cell(x,y)` returns a `Cell` instance from the Word document.  Calling `str()` on it retrieves its Unicode value and tries to encode it to a byte string using the `ascii` codec.  Since it contains non-ASCII characters it fails with `UnicodeEncodingError`.

In your later edit:

```
tyring = unicode((ListTables[0].Rows[x])).encode('utf-8')
tryingstring = tyring.encode('ascii')
print 'trying string' ,tryingstring
```

`unicode` does retrieve the Unicode value, converts it to a UTF-8 byte string, and stores it in `tyring`.  The next line tries to encode the byte string again to 'ascii'.  This isn't valid, because only Unicode strings can be encoded, so Python first attempts to convert the byte string back to a Unicode string using the default 'ascii' codec.  This causes a `UnicodeDecodingError` (not **Encoding**).

Best practice is to do all string processing in Unicode.  What you are missing is the `Range()` method to get the value of the cell.  Here's an example accessing a Word document table:

```
PythonWin 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2008 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> import win32com.client
>>> word=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
>>> word.ActiveDocument.Tables[0].Cell(1,1).Range()
u'One\u4e00\r\x07'
```

Note it is a Unicode string.  Word also seems to use `\r\x07` as a cell line terminator.

Now you can test the value:

```
>>> value = word.ActiveDocument.Tables[0].Cell(1,1).Range()
>>> value == 'One'   # NOTE: Python converts byte strings to Unicode via the default codec ('ascii' in Python 2.X)
False
>>> value == u'One'
False
>>> value == u'One马\r\x07'
False
>>> value == u'One一\r\x07'
True
>>> value == u'One\u4e00\r\x07'
True
>>> value == 'One\x92' # non-ASCII byte string fails to convert
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

Comment: @ Thanks for the explanation and advice code is working now after i tried this

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a Unicode string and use `encode()` *after* you convert it:

```
if tr1_find.search(unicode(ListTables[0].Cell(x,y)).encode('utf-8')):
```

Comment: @Abdi Bulle: I see, the issue happens in the conversion to string already. I corrected my answer - you should convert to a Unicode string, not an ASCII string. After that you can use `encode()` to get an ASCII string. Or you simply compare the Unicode string to your ASCII string - if the Unicode string contains non-ASCII characters then the comparison will simply be reported as not equal (which is what you want I guess).

Comment: Hi Wladimir when I try this as follows I get the                       tyring = unicode((ListTables[0].Rows[x])).encode('utf-8')                                                                                                   I get the same error as before

Comment: @Abdi: The thing is, it seems you are converting a unicode object to a string. You'll need to `encode` it to do that. By default, it uses the encoding `ascii`, which fails because you have non-ASCII characters. Wladimir's snippet should work. Could you update the question with the new information (such as the code you tried, the __exact__ error, etc.)?

Comment: @Abdi Bulle: And I guess the error message refers to the second line of your new example where you try to convert a UTF-8 string into ASCII? Why do you do that?

Comment: @ Wladimir Palant I have updated the Error message to be more inclusive but the error is actually in the first line

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm wondering if it might help:

`if tr1_find.search(unicode(ListTables[0].Cell(x,y)).encode('utf-8','ignore')):`

You might also find this page from Python's documentation helpful:
http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

It covers this exact sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the file using the `codecs.open()`? You can specify the file encoding in that function.

http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html